# jQuery kill .animate event

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to kill an event for a certian amount of time like for example:

```
$("#s").kill.aninmation(200);
```

Or if thats not possible is it possible to cancel an animation?

Comment: *kill for a certain amount of time* sounds like voodoo.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but `delay()` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: By that *wording*, I would think [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) is, as afterall - it's to 'end' the execution of an animation.

Comment: @MackieeE stop just does that-- stop. By his wording, he wants to essentially pause the animation for x time.

Comment: +1 for the `stop()` method. The two params you can pass in are `stop([clearQueue],[jumpToEnd])`. There's a great example of "pausing" an animation in the docs: http://api.jquery.com/stop/#example-0

Comment: You can try with either using `.stop(true,true)` or `.finish()` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try stop() it will make a query!